# Dynamic loading Leadtools DLLs

Tags: c++, windows, dll, leadtools-sdk

I am using Leadtools 17.5. If I statically link the Leadtools Dlls into my 64 bit C++ Application and then call `L_SetLicenseBuffer` everything works fine and the return value is zero. But for security reasons, the final product is not allowed to add those DLLs into the `System32` folder and is also not allowed to change the system path, and since multiple applications are using the tools I want to install them in a common folder (***C:\Program Files\Common Files\LeadTools\17.5*** for example) and use [AddDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513(v=vs.85).aspx) to add the path to the DLL search path. So I decided to load the DLLs dynamically at the run-time. So I created a definition for the function like this:

```
typedef L_INT (EXT_FUNCTION* TL_SetLicenseBuffer)(L_UCHAR* pLicenseBuffer, L_SSIZE_T nSize, L_TCHAR* pszDeveloperKey);
typedef L_BOOL (EXT_FUNCTION* TL_IsSupportLocked)(L_UINT uType);
```

then created a function pointer like this:

```
TL_SetLicenseBuffer pfSetLicenseBuffer = NULL;
TL_IsSupportLocked pfIsSupportLocked = NULL;
```

then add the paths to where the DLLs are to the DLL search path:

```
AddDllDirectory(LEAD_DLL_PATH);
AddDllDirectory(LEAD_FILTER_PATH);
```

and set the default directory search path for DLLs to be the user defined:

```
SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);
```

then load the DLL and get the address of the functions I need:

```
HINSTANCE hKrn = LoadLibrary(L"ltkrnx.dll");
pfSetLicenseBuffer = (TL_SetLicenseBuffer)GetProcAddress(hKrn, "L_SetLicenseBuffer");
pfIsSupportLocked  = (TL_IsSupportLocked)GetProcAddress(hKrn, "L_IsSupportLocked");
```

now if I use the function pointer with the same parameters as before, the function fails and returns -13 and any subsequent call to for example to `pfIsSupportLocked` shows the nag dialog:

```
retCode = pfSetLicenseBuffer(pLicenseData, LicSize, pKeyStr); // retCode is -13
pfIsSupportLocked(L_SUPPORT_DOCUMENT); // Shows nag dialog
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you
Sam

Comment: *If I statically link the Leadtools Dlls* -- You can't statically link DLL's in anything.  What you probably mean is that you use the import libraries in your project.

Comment: You should start by leaving the DLL's in the same place that worked when you didn't load them dynamically, and attempt to load them dynamically.  If that doesn't work, then issue is with your code, and not with moving things around your system and utilizing "AddDllDirectory".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know that. I have removed the static link and am only using the dynamic loading. What I was tying to say was the same function with the same parameter works when statically linked, but will fail when I switch to dynamic loading. Also I had added the DLLs into my System32 folder on the development machine. I cannot do that in production.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing.  First, a statically linked module implies you're using static libraries, thus no DLL's come into play at run time.   If you're using an import library, that is not "static linking" --.  You're still using DLL's -- the import library only contains "stubs" that tells the linker that the functions are located in an external module.  So you need to clarify what you mean by "static linking".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am sorry about the confusion. There are 2 methods of using DLLs, one is when when you link the .LIB file for a given DLL that contains the DLL's name and stubs. As far as I know, this is called static linking the DLL. The second method is where compiler/linker knows nothing about the DLL and in code you load the DLL using LoadLibrary and get the address of functions using GetProcAddress. That is called dynamic loading. I was trying to explain that the first method returns ***SUCCESS*** and the second method returns ***Invalid parameter passed***.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of both methods of using DLL's, as I've answered many questions on SO concerning the two ways.  However, I suggested that you first make sure that the calls to LoadLibrary are working correctly by keeping the DLL's in the same place where implicit linking worked.  If LoadLibrary works when the DLL's are in the same place where they worked when using implicit linking, then it more than likely becomes a path / missing helper DLL, or other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to make the dynamic loading to work at all, but I was able to use [Delay loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) to work.
What I had to do was to go back to linking the extracted .Lib files to my application and then tell compiler to load the associated DLLs with delay, which gave me a chance to create [Notification Hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h1h6ty.aspx) to ***__pfnDliNotifyHook2*** and ***__pfnDliFailureHook2*** and that way I could use [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) to load the delayed loaded Dlls from correct location.
But that only fixed half the problem because some of these Dlls are dependent on other DLLs and when I used the full path to load the DLL that I wanted, it could not find the secondary DLLs (which were located in the same directory as the one I was loading) and that would cause LoadLibrary to fail. The solution was to keep track of those dependencies and pre-load them. I am including some of the code to fix the issue for anyone whom might run into similar situation later on.
***P. S.*** I am using **Embarcadero's C++ Builder**, so Some of the objects like the `Strings`, `TStringList` and `Exception` may not be exactly what everyone is familiar with, but the concept should work in VC++ as well.

```
#include <map>

struct TDllDependency
{
    TStringList* Dependency;
    HMODULE hDll;

    __fastcall TDllDependency(void)
    {
        hDll = NULL;
        Dependency = new TStringList();
    }
    virtual __fastcall ~TDllDependency(void)
    {
        delete Dependency;
    }
};

class TDllModList : public std::map<System::String, TDllDependency>
{
public:
    void __fastcall CheckDependency(const System::String& aName);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
System::String __fastcall GetLtDllPath(void)
{
    wchar_t* pfPath = NULL;
    System::String dllPath;

    SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_ProgramFilesCommon, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &pfPath);
    if (NULL != pfPath)
    {
        dllPath = IncludeTrailingBackslash(pfPath) + L"LeadTools\\17.5\\";
        ::CoTaskMemFree(pfPath);
    }
    return dllPath;
}
System::String mDllPath(GetLtDllPath());
TDllModList DllModList;
void __fastcall InitDllDepends()
{
    DllModList.clear();
#if defined(_WIN64)
    DllModList[L"ltimgefxx.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisx.dll,ltimgutlx.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltefxx.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisx.dll,ltimgutlx.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltimgcorx.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisx.dll,ltimgutlx.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltdlgimgefxx.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisx.dll,ltdlgkrnx.dll,ltdlgcomx.dll,ltdlgctrlx.dll,ltdlgutlx.dll,ltimgefxx.dll,ltimgsfxx.dll,ltimgcorx.dll,ltimgclrx.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltdlgutlx.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisx.dll,ltfilx.dll,ltdlgkrnx.dll,ltimgclrx.dll,ltimgcorx.dll,ltimgefxx.dll,ltimgsfxx.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltdlgctrlx.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdlgutlx.dll,ltdlgkrnx.dll,ltdisx.dll,ltfilx.dll,ltimgefxx.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltdlgcomx.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdlgkrnx.dll,ltdlgctrlx.dll,ltdlgutlx.dll";
#elif defined(__WIN32__)
    DllModList[L"ltimgefxu.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisu.dll,ltimgutlu.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltefxu.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisu.dll,ltimgutlu.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltimgcoru.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisu.dll,ltimgutlu.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltdlgimgefxu.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisu.dll,ltdlgkrnu.dll,ltdlgcomu.dll,ltdlgctrlu.dll,ltdlgutlu.dll,ltimgefxu.dll,ltimgsfxu.dll,ltimgcoru.dll,ltimgclru.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltdlgutlu.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdisu.dll,ltfilu.dll,ltdlgkrnu.dll,ltimgclru.dll,ltimgcoru.dll,ltimgefxu.dll,ltimgsfxu.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltdlgctrlu.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdlgutlu.dll,ltdlgkrnu.dll,ltdisu.dll,ltfilu.dll,ltimgefxu.dll";
    DllModList[L"ltdlgcomu.dll"].Dependency->CommaText = L"ltdlgkrnu.dll,ltdlgctrlu.dll,ltdlgutlu.dll";
#endif
};
HMODULE SafeLoadLeadDll(const System::String tName)
{
    System::String tPath;
    HMODULE retVal = NULL;

    DllModList.CheckDependency(tName);
    tPath = mDllPath + tName;
    if(FileExists(tPath))
        retVal = ::LoadLibrary(tPath.c_str());
    return retVal;
}
FARPROC WINAPI MyDliNotifyHook(unsigned dliNotify, PDelayLoadInfo pdli)
{
    FARPROC retVal = NULL;
    System::String tStr(pdli->szDll);

    tStr = tStr.LowerCase();
    if(dliNotePreLoadLibrary == dliNotify)
    {
        TDllModList::iterator i = DllModList.find(tStr);

        if(DllModList.end() == i)
        {
            retVal = (FARPROC)SafeLoadLeadDll(tStr);
            DllModList[tStr].hDll = (HMODULE)retVal;
        }
        else if(NULL == i->second.hDll)
        {
            i->second.hDll = SafeLoadLeadDll(tStr);
            retVal = (FARPROC)i->second.hDll;
        }
        else
            retVal = (FARPROC)i->second.hDll;
    }
    else if(dliFailLoadLib == dliNotify)
    {
        tStr = L"Compleatly falied to load " + tStr;
        ::OutputDebugString(tStr.c_str());
    }
    return retVal;
}

FARPROC WINAPI MyDliFailureHook(unsigned dliNotify, PDelayLoadInfo pdli)
{
    FARPROC retVal = NULL;
    if(dliNotePreLoadLibrary == dliNotify)
    {
        System::String tMsg = pdli->szDll;

        tMsg = L"Failed to load \"" + tMsg + L"\".\n" + SysErrorMessage(::GetLastError());
        throw Exception(tMsg);
    }
    return retVal;
}

extern "C" PfnDliHook __pfnDliNotifyHook2 = MyDliNotifyHook;
extern "C" PfnDliHook __pfnDliFailureHook2 = MyDliFailureHook;
void __fastcall TDllModList::CheckDependency(const System::String& aName)
{
    TDllModList::iterator i = find(aName);

    if(end() != i)
    {
        int len = i->second.Dependency->Count;
        int j;
        System::String tPath;

        for(j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            if(end() == find(i->second.Dependency->Strings[j]))
            {
                CheckDependency(i->second.Dependency->Strings[j]);
                tPath = mDllPath + i->second.Dependency->Strings[j];
                (*this)[i->second.Dependency->Strings[j]].hDll = ::LoadLibrary(tPath.c_str());
            }
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And of course `InitDllDepends();` should be called at the beginning of `WinMain` to set things up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is check the debugger output and make sure that the DLL you are expecting to get loaded is the one getting loaded by verifying the path. It is possible that you have multiple versions of LTKRNX.DLL in your search path. I have tested your code here and it returned SUCCESS:

```
typedef L_INT (EXT_FUNCTION* TL_SetLicenseBuffer)(L_UCHAR* pLicenseBuffer, L_SSIZE_T nSize, L_TCHAR* pszDeveloperKey);
typedef L_BOOL (EXT_FUNCTION* TL_IsSupportLocked)(L_UINT uType);

HINSTANCE hKrn = LoadLibrary(L"ltkrnx.dll");
TL_SetLicenseBuffer pfSetLicenseBuffer = NULL;
TL_IsSupportLocked pfIsSupportLocked = NULL;

pfSetLicenseBuffer = (TL_SetLicenseBuffer)GetProcAddress(hKrn, "L_SetLicenseBuffer");
pfIsSupportLocked  = (TL_IsSupportLocked)GetProcAddress(hKrn, "L_IsSupportLocked");

L_INT retCode = pfSetLicenseBuffer(szLICAnsi, _countof(szLICAnsi), pKeyStr);
if(retCode == SUCCESS)
  bRet = pfIsSupportLocked(L_SUPPORT_DOCUMENT);
else
  printf("Problem!");
```

Also what PaulMcKenzie suggested is another way to verify that your calls to LoadLibrary are working correctly. If you still cannot figure it out, you can contact our Technical Support to assist you with this issue at support@leadtools.com